# Preferred Way to Reuse Variable in a Loop in Java

Tags: java, idioms

Out of the following, which is the preferred way of reusing the `section` vector?

```
Iterator<Vector> outputIter = parsedOutput.iterator();

while(outputIter.hasNext()) {
    Vector section = outputIter.next();
}
```

or

```
Vector section = null;

while(outputIter.hasNext()) {
    section = outputIter.next();
}
```

Comment: Another thing: there's a good chance that you should be using ArrayList instead of Vector. Vector is synchronized - it's safe to modify from multiple threads, but if you're not doing that, then the synchronization just adds overhead.

Comment: Will keep this in mind for the future. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `Vector` is very old school, common in the late 90s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second way means that the variable `section` is visible outside the loop. If you're not using it outside of the loop, then there's no need to do that, so use the first option. As far as performance, there shouldn't be any visible difference.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer the second version since you don't have an unused variable in your scope after the loop finishes.

However, what about

```
for (Vector section: parsedOutput) {
    ...
}
```

?

Comment: I've never seen this syntax. Could you provide a link to its documentation?

Comment: @Alex, this is a called the "enhanced for loop" and was introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `section` outside the loop then your first style would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively I'd choose the second variant of your solution. But finally it pretty much depends on the optimizier, it might change your code anyway. Try to compile your code and then look at the generated bytecodes to see what happened. You can use javap to see what is generated or any other available decompiler.

Finally even then the code might be optimized in even another way during runtime.